# how do I fix this errror? ; error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{ ' token

Tags: c++, arrays

This program makes use of a 2D array to count stock inside a furniture shop. This code works fine on a online C++ compiler but not on codeblocks. I dont understand why

```
   

   #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;
    
    int main()
    
    {   int i=0, j=0;
        int Stock_Items=3;
        int NR_materials=3;
        int total_items=0;
        int leather_items=0;
        cout << "Hello user! Welcome to the furniture program \n" << endl;
        std::cout<<"This program works using a 2 D array \n \n It calculates the amount of stock in the shop and the amount of leather items"<<"\n";
        //declaration of 2 dimensional array with all items in the shop
        //This array consists of 3 rows and 3 columns- 3 furniture type and 3 materials
        int stockArray[Stock_Items][NR_materials]= {{50,10,20},{40,50,60},{30,20,10}};
        //For loop for calculating total amount of items in the shop
        for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++ )//rows
        {
            for ( j = 0; j < 3; j++ )//columns
            {
                total_items+=stockArray[i][j];//sum
    
            }
        }
    
    //For loop for calculating total amount of leather items in the shop
        for (i=0; i<3; i++)//rows- goes through all rows
        {
            for(j=1; j<2; j++)//coloumns- only goes through coloumn 1
            {
                leather_items+=stockArray[i][j];//sum
            }
        }//display results to the UI
        std::cout<<"The total amount of stock in the shop is: "<<total_items<<" items. \n \n";
        std::cout<<"The total amount of leather items is: "<<leather_items<<" items.\n \n";
    
        return 0;

}
```

Comment: please include the complete error message in the question. In which line is the error?

Comment: [Couldn't reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Y1IVCjRD4O4BxFrx) after adding `#include <iostream>`. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Check if there aren't extra lines that you may forgot to erase before or after the code.

Comment: I think there might be some misconfiguration in your codeblocks IDE, I tried this code in my CodeBlocks and it worked absolutely fine

Comment: Your compiler should tell you what line of code that the error occurs on. My guess is you have somehow corrupted your mingw headers.

Comment: I think it could be my codeblocks being problematic as when I ran the code now it worked. Perhaps it should been worth mentioning that sometimes when I open codeblocks, I get an error then I am unable to open any projects-- I restart then it works

Comment: Thank you everyone for the support!

Comment: LOL and its supposed to be the latest Codeblocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding `#include<iostream>` at the top and changing

```
int Stock_Items=3;
int NR_materials=3;
```

to

```
const int Stock_Items=3;
const int NR_materials=3;
```

to get rid of that "variable-sized object may not be initialized" error, your code worked fine in Visual Studio Code on my Mac.

Alex

Comment: For both of these answers the error message is different from what the OP claims. However I don't see how the claimed error is in the code that is presented.

Comment: Thanks bro, appreciated. Works perfect on Codeblocks now. Yours and mine. What does const do though, it worked using const as well

Comment: Mac is cool though, I feel like getting one to learn Swift

Answer (score 2):

I tried compiling your code in code blocks and found an error in this line :

```
int stockArray[Stock_Items][NR_materials]= {{50,10,20},{40,50,60},{30,20,10}};
```

And the compiler error was :

```
compiler error: in build2_stat, at tree.c:4160|
warning: array of array of runtime bound [-Wvla]|
```

I tried fixing the array length from variable to fixed static numbers. So I changed the above line like this :

```
int stockArray[3][3]= {{50,10,20},{40,50,60},{30,20,10}};
```

Then the code worked properly.

Comment: You probably should have made `Stock_Items` and `NR_materials` const or constexpr

Comment: For both of these answers the error message is different from what the OP claims. However I don't see how the claimed error is in the code that is presented.